# HTML Code with Image links are not displaying images

Tags: html, vba, image

Im looking for a way to be able to display images in a html file.

I use excel vba to take the HTML code and save it into a .HTML file and it displays the text and formatting fine. But does not display any images. The HTML code does have links to images like this:

```
<h1><img src="**********/Image.png" alt="" /></h1>
```

I've tried saving as a .MHTML but this comes up blank, and i have tried saving in other formats such as word documents but they just fail.

Is there anything i am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the image path is correct.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that i can open the link on a web browser and it opens fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That HTML seems to be valid.
For example,

```
<h1><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png" alt="" /></h1>
```

works for me.

It's somewhat unclear what you are doing with Excel here, but is it maybe just that the paths to the images are invalid, maybe because they are relative?
Have you tried opening it in Chrome's F12 and looking for the problem there?